# Why does the linker complain “file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked” when the architecture is correct?

Tags: macos, clang, ld, unix-ar

When trying to build a binary (see MWE below) that links a static library using clang I am getting the following error message:

```
⟩⟩⟩ clang -o test bar.a test.o
ld: warning: ignoring file bar.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): bar.a
> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:  
>   "_bar", referenced from:  
>       _main in test.o  
>   "_foo", referenced from:  
>       _main in test.o  
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

But the architecture is *correct* and *consistent* (x86_64) according to `lipo`:

```
⟩⟩⟩ lipo -info test.o bar.a
input file bar.a is not a fat file
Non-fat file: test.o is architecture: x86_64
Non-fat file: bar.a is architecture: x86_64
```

`otools -hv` shows similar output. **All object files are built for x86_64**. So what does this error message mean?

---

Here’s a complete, minimal, working example to reproduce the problem shown above:

- `foo.c`:

  ```c
  int foo(void) {
      return 1;
  }
  ```
- `bar.c`:

  ```c
  int bar(void) {
      return 2;
  }
  ```
- `test.c`:

  ```c
  #include <stdio.h>

  int foo(void);
  int bar(void);

  int main(void) {
      printf("foo = %d\n", foo());
      printf("bar = %d\n", bar());
  }
  ```

Compilation:

```sh
clang -c -o foo.o foo.c
ar rcs foo.a foo.o

clang -c -o bar.o bar.c
ar rcs bar.a foo.a bar.o

clang -c -o test.o test.c
clang -o test bar.a test.o
```

Comment: There are many other questions with this error message but these are all concerned with actual architecture mismatches due to cross-compilation. I’ve asked this question because it’s currently impossible to google the error message for somebody experiencing the same problem as me. Hope this helps somebody else.

Comment: And, in case anybody is interested in anecdotes: debugging and fixing this issue has taken me several days in a complex code base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is in fact misleading: The issue isn’t a mismatch in architecture, it’s the fact static libraries (`.a` files) cannot be nested:

```
⟩⟩⟩ nm bar.a

bar.a(bar.o):
0000000000000000 T _bar
```

(Note that the entry `_foo` from `foo.a` is missing!)

But since `ar` is originally a general-purpose archival utility, it has no qualms creating a nested archive via

```bash
ar rcs bar.a foo.a bar.o
```

As we can verify by listing its contents:

```
⟩⟩⟩ ar t bar.a
__.SYMDEF SORTED
foo.a
bar.o
```

To fix the problem, don’t nest archives but rather pack the object files directly:

```bash
rm bar.a
ar rcs bar.a foo.o bar.o
clang -o test bar.a test.o
```